# How to cut string after a specific word?

Tags: string, batch-file, delimiter, cut

How do I cut strings like these in my .bat file as soon as the string `, TARO/` appears?

```
Init., 12, TARO/ BLA BLA CDE
Ademanto, TARO/ BLA BLA XYZ
```

I only want to have `Init., 12` and `Ademanto` afterwards.

I cannot use the delimiter in FOR, as it is limited to only one single character, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a more robust solution that should work even if the string contains quotes or poison characters - replace the cutoff string with a new line character. FOR /F will iterate each resultant line, so use GOTO to break out of the loop and preserve just the first line.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "string=;Init., 12, TARO/ BLA BLA CDE"
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set ^"string=!string:, TARO/=^

!^"
for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("!string!") do (
  endlocal
  set "string=%%A"
  goto :break
)
:break
set string
```

Comment: too fancy for me. I don't get this one. Sorry.

Comment: Alright, I've come to my senses. Your solution is much better.
Can you adjust it in a way that I can check for several strings, like `, TARO`, `, TARI` and `, TARU`?

Answer (score 6):

`set` is able to cut from beginning to a defined string, but not from a defined string to the end. Using a little trick helps:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "string=Init., 12, TARO/ BLA BLA CDE" 
set "str=%string:*TARO/=TARO/%"
echo "!string:%str%=!"
```

(replace start of string including the delimiter-string (`*TARO/`) with the delimiter string only (`TARO/`). In a second step, remove the found string)

Another way is to replace the delimiter-string with a single char delimiter (any char that is sure not to be in the string. (The strange symbol below (`þ`) is a `chr(127)`, but you can also use `@`, `#` or any other char that isn't in your string(s))

```
for /f "delims=þ" %%i in ("%string:TARO/=þ%") do echo %%i
```

Comment: as soon as you replace `string1` by `string` in your `echo` command line (ehich I guess is just a typo), your answer works if there are no poisonous characters like `"` or `=` in the initial string, and if it does not start with `*` or `~`...

Answer (score 6):

There's one other way.  Replace `, TARO/` with `&rem;`.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "str=Init., 12, TARO/ BLA BLA CDE"
set str=%str:, TARO/=&rem;%

echo %str%
```

That works because the variable is expanded before the `set` command is evaluated.  So when the line is evaluated, it's evaluated as...

```js
set str=Init.,12&rem; BLAH BLAH CDE
```

... as a compound command of `set var=value & rem (rest of line ignored)`

You could also `echo %str:, TARO/=&rem;%` and achieve the same effect.

Comment: Should work well as long as the string does not contain quote or poison character before the cutoff string, which is certainly true for the example text.