# Azure YAML expression for removing some value within the parameter value

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines

What is the right syntax for removing a particular value in a parameter in a Azure YAML pipeline?

Scenario:

```
Parameters:
 - name: App_Name
   type: string
   values: ABC_CARD_GAME
           ABC_CARD_GAME2
           ABC_CARD_GAME3


Echo ${{parameters.App_Name}}
```

For example: If I choose `ABC_CARD_GAME` from the list, the desired result would be `CARD_GAME` (without the `ABC`).

I tried using the replace expression but that is not what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Not sure that I understand your question correctly But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62343942/can-i-substring-a-variable-in-azure-pipelines

Comment: `replace` is exactly what you need to use if you want to remove a substring from a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [replace or split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace) expressions.

Sample Yaml:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  
parameters:
  - name: App_Name
    type: string
    values:
      - ABC_CARD_GAME1
      - ABC_CARD_GAME2
      - ABC_CARD_GAME3

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world! This is  ${{ replace(parameters.App_Name, 'ABC_', '') }}
  displayName: 'replace'

- script: echo Hello, world! This is  ${{ split(parameters.App_Name, '_')[1] }}_${{ split(parameters.App_Name, '_')[2] }}
  displayName: 'split'
```

[image: Result1]

[image: Result2]

Comment: This solves my issue :) Thanks so much!